# Cant get Scene to render in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, data-visualization

I'm pretty new to three.js and I can't seem to get my scene (or camera) to render. The other parts are working (I am able to render my adobe illustrator vectors that I converted just fine), however if I comment out my scene, camera & renderer code it makes no difference to what's rendered in the browser.

Here is my html:

```
<canvas id ="slot">
</canvas>
```

Here is my js:

```
var c = document.getElementById('slot');
c.height = 282;
c.width = 400;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');

//This doesn't appear to be working ...
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 
);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

//Working just fine
cx.fillStyle="rgba(255,255,255,0)";
cx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
cx.fillRect(1,0,1,1);
//....(goes on and on)

var slot = new THREE.Mesh(cx);

// GridHelper
var size = 10;
var divisions = 10;
var gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( size, divisions )

// Light
var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);

// Fog
var fogColor = 0xFFFFFF;
var near = 10;
var far = 100;
var fog = new THREE.Fog(fogColor, near, far)

scene.add(slot, gridHelper, light, fog)

camera.position.z = 5;

renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: any messages from f12?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D.

Comment: Stripping out everything but the three.js set-up stuff and inserting the cube example (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene) and the cube is shown, so the part you commented as doesn't appear to be working, is working. The error @will just posted is a result of an issue with `THREE.Fog` so perhaps that is the root of your problem.

Comment: Why do you pass that canvas context `cx` as a parameter in `THREE.Mesh` constructor, whereas it expects a geometry and a material?

Comment: @JDunken thank you. if i comment out the fog code i'm left with: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined (which refers to this line) --> renderer.render( scene, camera );

Comment: @prisoner849 I have no good reason for this. If i comment out the line it doesn't make any difference to what's being rendered in the browser. All I'm trying to do is add a grid, light & fog to my canvas but scene.add() doesn't appear to be doing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have prepared a jsFiddle with your corrected code.

https://jsfiddle.net/EthanHermsey/qampc5b1/49/

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});

var cTexture = new THREE.CanvasTexture( c );

var slot = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2, 2),
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({     
    map: cTexture,
    transparent: true
  })
);
scene.add(slot);

scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(fogColor, near, far);
```

1. You cant initialize a Mesh like that.
2. You have to add the canvas as a CanvasTexture to a material.
3. You cant .add() fog to the scene, it is like this: scene.fog = new THREE.Fog().
   This is what gave the error message.
4. I don't think you can add multiply objects to the scene like that. (but i'm not sure)
5. Added antialias to the render (makes edges smoother).

Comment: thank you so much for this. I can't begin to tell you how much this helped me. Is there any way to render just the bottom half? (the squares with the grid helper / lights / fog - as opposed to just the squares up top).

Comment: Great to hear and happy to help :) There is; with 'the squares up top' you mean that canvas on which you draw, right? In the HTML do this: <canvas id ="slot" style="display: none"></canvas> Or, if you have a seperate css file: #slot{display: none;}

Comment: OR; don't add it to the DOM (html) at all ;p var c = document.createElement('canvas');

Comment: I only now see that you tagged data-visualization.. in 2d or 3d? There might be a more efficient solution to this? Do you write once to the canvas, or multiple times? You could maybe write data to a dataTexture? Pass an array with rgb color data for every pixel.